# want to position glyphicon-search at right end of page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position my glyphicon-search icon at right end.

```
<div  id="search" > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></i> 
</div>
```

if i add different class name for my div and give style to float:right its working but , the corresponding click  function is not working.

```
$('#search').click(function(e) {
    $('#example_filter').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try to align with the css positioning

```
 #search{
   position:relative;
   width:/*your element width */
   height:/*your element height*/
 }
 #search glyphicon.glyphicon-search{
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   width:/*your element width */
   height:/*your element height*/
 }
```